# How to avoid leading white space while joining string

Tags: python, string

I have a list of float which I form them into a string with the following method:

```
import json
a = [1.2, 2.9, 7.4]
str = "\t".join(format(x,"10.3f") for x in a)
print json.dumps(str)
```

However the final result of `str` contain leading whitespace like this:

```
"     1.200\t     2.900\t     7.400"
```

How can I get this kind of result instead:

```
"1.200\t2.900\t7.400"
```

Comment: Just `.strip()` it after join?

Comment: No. `str.strip()` only remove the first whitespace but not the alternate one.

Comment: If you are only interested in leading spaces, lstrip is a more precise choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to strip (using `strip()`) the elements of the generator expression:

```
s = "\t".join(format(x, "10.3f").strip() for x in a)
```

**Demo:**

```
import json
a = [1.2, 2.9, 7.4]
s = "\t".join(format(x, "10.3f").strip() for x in a)
print json.dumps(s) # "1.200\t2.900\t7.400"
```

**Note:**

- Don't use `str` as the name of a variable because it will hide the built-in implementation of `str`.

Answer (score 1):

Numbers are padded to 10 characters because of the format you've specified.

Try to use `0` as width specifier to obtain "zero-padding for numeric types":

```
str = "\t".join(format(x,"0.3f") for x in a)
```

Have a look at python documentation:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language